# How To Print ASCII Extended Characters Using a Const Char*?

Tags: c, variables, bios, vga, extended-ascii

I have  a function to print characters on the screen that is like this:

```
void print(int colour, int y, int x, const char *string)
{
   volatile char *video=(volatile char*)0xB8000 + y*160 + x*2;
   while(*string != 0)
   {
      *video=*string;
      string++;
      video++;
      *video=colour;
      video++;
   }
}
```

And I want to print the character [254 in decimal](http://www.asciitable.com/), but I need to use stored on a `const char*`. I can't try `print(0x0F, 0, 0, 0xFE);`, because this trows a error of pointer without cast, then how can I do this?

Comment: Eek. What's with the magic number `0xB8000`?

Comment: Hey, that's the core of Nathan's operating system - don't dis it.

Comment: Nathan, it is not the address of any interrupt, a term you obviously do not know the meaning of. This question is well up there with some of your other classics.

Comment: Ops! The interrupt for this is `10h`, `0xB8000` is the pointer that is aimed at the video card.

Comment: @GMan: Man! That brings back memories of writing directly to video memory. 0xB800 is the segment where the vga's video memory is accessible from bios. 0xb000 is the monochrome vga.

Comment: @Neill: I rofl'd. @Tommie: Surprisingly, I actually knew that. At my age I'm not even suppose to know what punch cards are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embed the character in the string using C's hex notation:

```
print(0x0f, 0, 0, "\xfe");
```

As folks have pointed out, you might want to pretty up the code a bit, perhaps by adding a symbolic name for the [VGA framebuffer base address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA#Addressing_details).

Answer (score 1):

This is off-topic, memories of this, but digging up the code I found this:

```
/* Global Variables */
static Word far *ScrPtr;

/* Local Variables */
static Word VidSeg;
...

int WinScreenHeight(void)
{
    return (*(unsigned char far *) 0x484) + 1;
}

int WinScreenWidth(void)
{
    return (*(unsigned int far *) 0x44A);
}

void WinInit(){
   SetMode(AdapterType());
   ScrPtr = (Word far *) CreateFarPtr(VidSeg, 0x0000);
}

static void SetMode(int VideoAddress)
{
    switch(VideoAddress)
    {
        case VGA :
        case MCGA:
        case EGA :
        case CGA :  (Word) VidSeg = 0xB800;
                    break;
        case MDA :  (Word) VidSeg = 0xB000;
                    break;
        case '?' :  fprintf(stderr, "Sorry Unknown Video Adapter.\n");
                    fprintf(stderr, "This program requires C/E/MC/VGA, Mono Adapter\n");
                    exit(1);
    }
}
static int AdapterType(void)
{
    char far *VidMode;
    char blreg, alreg;
    VidMode = (char far *) 0x00000449L;
    asm mov ax, 0x1a00;
    asm push bp;
    asm int 0x10;
    asm pop bp;
    asm mov blreg, bl;
    asm mov alreg, al;
    if (alreg == 0x1a && blreg >= 9) return(MCGA);
    if (alreg == 0x1a && blreg >= 7 && blreg <= 9) return(VGA);
    if (blreg == 4 || blreg == 5) return(EGA);
    if (*VidMode == 3) return(CGA);
    if (*VidMode == 7) return(MDA);
    return('?');
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: This is too much helpful! I'm going to save this code to take a better look. Thanks very much! **:-)**

Comment: @Nathan: I'm curious - why? :) Those old skool stuff gave me happy memories... :)

Comment: @Nathan: I can provide more code if I can dig out some more code...drop a line here eh? :) ;)